# Will the resId of a menu item ever change it's value if the android:id attribute is not changed?

Tags: android

I'm wondering if I define a menu and I have a menu item such as:

```
<item android:id="@+id/my_menu_item" />
```

If I store the integer value of this resId in my app preferences and attempt to reference it after I open the app again, will it have changed?

For example:

```
storeInAppPreferences(R.id.my_menu_item)

---- App Restart --------------------------

storedMenuItem = storedAppPreferences.storedValue
randomFunctionNameWhichTakesMenuItem(storedMenuItem)
```

Will this resId integer value ever change once it has been defined if I never change `android:id="@+id/my_menu_item"`

Comment: I really believe it can change when you compile your app again. Just map each menu item to a string, and save the string.

Comment: Why you want to store your `menu_item` id in `AppPreferences`

Comment: It is going to change with the app update (changes in the code). I think that it would change for sure when you add another resource to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID changes at every compilation.

You don't need to save that ID because it is used to refers to that item menu and it don't hold any other useful meaning/purpose.

Comment: Right, but if I wanted to store that that menu item was 'selected' before closing the app per say and hence navigate to that menu option on start then I would need to reference it. Thanks for the answer regardless!